# Send error report to sentry within Laravel queue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sentry, laravel-queue

I have Sentry.io set-up on my Laravel project. I'm also using Queues.

I was wondering if it was possible to send failed queues to Sentry? As they don't automatically send when they fail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By failed queues I guess you mean failed jobs, for that you just need to implement the `failed()` method inside the job:

```
/**
 * Handle a job failure.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function failed(\Exception $exception)
{
    // Send exception data to sentry.io
    // It should catch it by default since it throws an exception
    // But you can force a report manually
    app('sentry')->captureException($exception);
}
```

Check how to deal with failed jobs in [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs).

Comment: Just adding more context, this is also specified in Sentry documentation (Since the answer is from 2018, I also want to mention that when I am adding this comment we are on Laravel 10): 
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/laravel/usage/#queue-jobs

Answer (score 2):

If you added the following snippet to your error handler ([as described here](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-laravel#installation)), all uncatched exceptions (also when thrown in queue jobs) are catched as long as they pass the `->shouldReport()` check.

```
if (app()->bound('sentry') && $this->shouldReport($exception)) {
    app('sentry')->captureException($exception);
}
```